# How to load an Entity from another entity on Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have 2 entities

1   `Surgery/PatientBundle/Entity/Patients`

2   `Surgery\LoginBundle\Entity\User`

In want in Patients get to User's entity method getIdUser and  use into Patients. I tried used

```
use Surgery\LoginBundle\Entity\User;
```

in Patients entity but it didn't work. I still getting the error "Call to undefined function"

Comment: I suggest to start from http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: I'm too stupid It's didn't help me ;( I must create OneToOne relation ?

Comment: I handled with it , I created OneToOne relationship and this code  $entity->setUser($this->getUser()); doing all job :D